# how I can find the generators's of Primitive Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap

Could anyone please tell me how in GAP I can get a set of generators for a given primitive group (such as `PrimitiveGroup(15,2)`)?

Comment: Please include more context.

Comment: I need someone who can work with Sage or Gap, it is impossible to find generators with hand. if you are familiar with these software, I think my question is obvious

Comment: Did you search [this page](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup_named.html) (for Sage)? Using ctrl+F, the sixth occurrence of "primitive" gives an example during which `G.gens()` is called to display a list of generators.

Comment: could you please use it and find Primitive Group(25,2) , I am not good in programing at all, but I need the generators of this group for my reaserch

Comment: @pjs36 could you please use it and find Primitive Group(25,2) , I am not good in programing at all, but I need the generators of this group for my reaserch –

Comment: The standard command in GAP would be to first create the group `G:=PrimitiveGroup(15,2);` and then ask for `GeneratorsOfGroup(G);` which will fetch the stored generators.

Comment: @ahulpke could you please tell me what I should write if I want the group elements?

Comment: @shere: please see http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.6. Also there is an example in http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/01-command-line/

Comment: @ahulpke Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

The standard command in GAP would be to first create the group `G:=PrimitiveGroup(15,2);` and then ask for `GeneratorsOfGroup(G);` which will fetch the stored generators.

Note that these generators might not be "nice" in any particular sense.